# Border around radio button

Tags: html, css, radio-button, styles, border

Here is what I want to achieve:

[image: here is the link to the border]

Can anyone help me replicate the border used there? I wrote the code for the radio buttons, they work but I just cant figure out how to do that border, how does the border stop before and after the word?

any help would be so appreciated!

Comment: https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/fieldset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your radio buttons with a `<fieldset></fieldset>` tag and your text with a `<legend></legend>` tag.

### Example

```
<form>
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Personalia:</legend>
  Name: <input type="text"><br>
  Email: <input type="text"><br>
  Date of birth: <input type="text">
 </fieldset>
</form>
```